# El compilador no detecta la libreria gnuplot-iostream.h

Tags: c++, gnuplot

Hola estoy intentando representar segmentos en gnuplot a traves de c++ y en todos lados veo que deberia usar gnuplot-iostream.h y en los ejemplos de codigo colocan un:

```
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"
```

pero me dice que no se ha encontrado el archivo. Estoy en windows 10 en qt creator, si alguien sabe si necesito descargar un archivo y me pudiera facilitar un link de descarga se lo agradeceria.

Comment: No está incluida dentro de la librería estándar de C++, debes instalarla o clonarla del [repositorio](https://github.com/dstahlke/gnuplot-iostream), siguiendo las instrucciones que te dan.

Answer (score 1):

C++ incluye una vasta biblioteca (library) estándar.  Para poder usar una no estándar, primero tenés que instalarla en tu computadora.

Usualmente el archivo .h (archivo header) es sólo la interfaz para conectarse con la biblioteca instalada.  No es suficiente descargar sólo ese archivo.

Cada desarrollador tiene su manera de desarrollar, pero lo más usual es que te proporcione instrucciones para la instalación de la biblioteca.  Los motivos por el que no te dan un instalador como pasa con muchos programas de Windows son dos:

- no estás instalando una aplicación, estás instalando una biblioteca para usar desde tu código
- esas bibliotecas suelen ser multiplataforma, y se pueden usar en Windows, Android, Linux y demás.  El típico instalador de Windows no funciona en las otras plataformas

Luego de instalada hay que encontrar el archivo .h .  Usualmente ese archivo queda accesible sin necesidad de conocer la ruta, pero conviene indicarlo así:

```
#include <gnuplot-iostream.h>
```

usando <> en lugar de "" .

Comment: *Esto puede variar entre IDEs (la aplicación de desarrollo), es una convención no estándar.* Esto no depende del IDE (no tiene nada que ver). Ya que los signos "<>" o comillas, es una sintaxis que expresamente el pre-procesador lo entiende y claro que es estándar (aquí mismo lo dice: [19.2 Source file inclusion](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf), es la página 406).

Comment: Básicamente cuando usas "<>" el pre-procesador buscara el archivo de cabecera en la carpeta `include` que viene por defecto cuando instalamos el compilador y cuando usamos las comillas (como por ejemplo: `#include "stdio.h"`), se le indica al pre-procesador que debe buscar el archivo en el directorio actual donde se esté compilando y si la búsqueda falla, lo busca en el directorio por defecto.